# Can no longer browse my ASP.NET web app on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, iis, web-server, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

Can't browse the ASP.NET web app that I built with Visual Studio 2015. Web app is on Azure VM Windows Server 2012 R2. Can't browse localhost/ from VM, can't browse from Internet. Both used to work.

BACKGROUND: Last November, I de-allocated the VM, to save money. A week ago I re-allocated VM.  But now can't browse web app.
 I can RDP to VM ok. VM can browse Google ok. VM > IIS > cannot browse the virtual web app. I get: "This page can’t be displayed"

VM > IE browser > localhost/ ... doesn't browse.

Comment: Are the needed service up and running? Is the pool running in iis?

Comment: Was the site configured to use SSL?  Could be certificate errors.

Comment: Also try setting up a new blank site and see if that works